# Batch Delete Domain Shared Contacts With PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

- I am using Google API PHP [Client Library v2.1.3](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)
- I am following the documentation for [Domain Shared Contacts](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/#Deleting)
- I am following the batch [processing guidelines](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/batch#delete-operations) for delete

Here is the logic I'm using:

```
$xmlBuild = "<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/'
    xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
    xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'>";
$xmlBuild .= "<entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
    xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'>";
$xmlBuild .= "<batch:id>1</batch:id><batch:operation type='delete'/>";
$xmlBuild .= "<id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/my.domain/base/1b93ef80b806243</id>";
$xmlBuild .= "<link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/my.domain/full/1b93ef80b806243/1812952240373020'/>";
$xmlBuild .= "</entry>";
$xmlBuild .= "</feed>";

$len = strlen($xmlBuild);
$options = array(
    "headers" => array(
        "Content-type" => "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8;",
        "Content-lenght" => $len
    ),
    "body" => $xmlBuild
);

$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$request = $httpClient->delete("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/my.domain/full/batch", $options); 
$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();

print_r($response); //This prints "Contact ID not found."

// ??? why ???
```

I'm pretty sure I am doing everything correct. To me,it seems a buggy behavior. I already searched for any example that shows how to do this to no avail. Is anyone here capable of determining if there is something wrong with my logic? Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

P.D. The insert method works like a charm. The problem is only with deleting the contacts. I haven't tested the update method yet but it all points out to be almost the same as the delete. There is no problem in doing the deletion without batching.

Comment: What if you try other batching methods like Adding or Updating, is it also not working?

Comment: @noogui The adding works fine when I'm doing the batching insert. The delete is the one that it is not working. I have sent request with and without  `<link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/my.domain/full/1b93ef80b806243/1812952240373020'/>` and it still won't work. So unfortunate there is no example on the documentation on how to batch delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the mistake is because you send a DELETE http verb instead of a POST. Also, the XML namespace attributes in the entry are not required.

By the way, maybe this is a typo, you wrote 'content-len**ght**' instead of content-len**gth**.

Don't send any content in the entry for deletions, as it's not required (and not documented).

```
$xmlBuild = "<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
    xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'>";
$xmlBuild .= "<entry>";
$xmlBuild .= "<batch:id>1</batch:id><batch:operation type='delete'/>";
$xmlBuild .= "<id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/my.domain/base/1b93ef80b806243</id>";
$xmlBuild .= "</entry>";
$xmlBuild .= "</feed>";

$len = strlen($xmlBuild);
$options = array(
    "headers" => array(
        "Content-type" => "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8;",
        "Content-length" => $len
    ),
    "body" => $xmlBuild
);

$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$request = $httpClient->post("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/my.domain/full/batch", $options); 
// or $request = $httpClient->sendRequest('POST', "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/my.domain/full/batch", $options); 

$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();

print_r($response);
```